# Transform badly formatted excel data into a form for pivot tables

Tags: excel

How can I transform data in excel in this form (see image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5EDj.jpg) into something suitable for using in a pivot chart. I need three columns eventually, Date, Country and Score. The amount of data points for each country is not constant.

Comment: do you mind using some VBA? can we assume there will always be a `Date` field after the country name?

Comment: Yes, always a date field. There may also be some blank lines to be ignored between the countries.
Although it's picky, I'd rather not use VBA as I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way i found without using VBA is to use an array formula :

- Add another column on the left of your values (let say `Col A`)
- Set this formula on cell `A1`: `{=INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF(ISEMPTY($C$1:C1),ROW($C$1:C1),ROW($C$1))))}`
- Validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Drag the formula till the end of your values

Your data are almost suitable for a Pivot Chart. What you can do next is to delete unneeded rows (with country names and headers) or use another formula on another sheet to "duplicate" the data except when unwanted rows (you can then filter the blank data in the pivot chart).